# Systemprofile Temp Internet Files Location Bloating

Tags: files, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem with Temporary Internet Files (Specifically wsusscn.cab files) filling up the local drive in the following location "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5".

This location is not controlled through the Logged on user's IE session as Temp Internet Files for the logged on user exist in "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files" so running a delete from the Browsing history section doesn't make a difference.

Space can be restricted from this section too so have some level of control be it manually or through GPO but how do I control the systemprofile location?

I'm thinking this will be more a Computer Configuration setting through GPO rather than User Configuration as would normally be the case for controlling user settings seeing as this is the system profile so possibly a setting under "Computer Config > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > General Page > Browsing History"?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like this is to do with MSBA as is the tool which creates wsusscn2.cab by the looks of it.

http://clintboessen.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/perform-offline-mbsa-scan.html:

> First you must have an up to date catalog file of all the updates that
>   are available via microsoft update. Obviously you need to get to a PC
>   with an internet connection to obtain this. The file that contains the
>   update information is called wsusscn2.cab. This is always changing as
>   new updates are released... but you can always download the latest
>   copy by going to this link

This explains the file but not why there's hundreds of them in this location and why they're there when I've not downloaded them manually!? I am running an old version of MSBA on this server (v2.0) so am going to upgrade this to the latest version (v2.3) to see if this fixes the issue.